# Simply connected domain under analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic and one-to-one that is defined on a simpliy connected domain $D$, I am struggling with showing that $f(D)$ is simply connected as well, I'll appreciate hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@José Carlos Santos’s argument is correct, but perhaps a slightly more elementary argument can be welcome.

$f$ is analytic, hence continuous and open. As $f$ is one to one, $f$ has open image and is a homeomorphism onto its image, and the conclusion follows.

Comment: It might be helpful to elaborate on how openness makes $f$ a homeomorphism. A one-to-one map being open makes its inverse continuous, since then images under $f$ are pre-images under $f^{-1}$. And then openness of $f$ is the same as continuity of $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $f$ is continuous and one-to-one, it follows from [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) that it is a homeomorphism onto its image.